# ElasticSearch Failed to build [request] after last required field arrived

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am doing a ranking evaluation using ElasticSearch on the [LinkSO](https://sites.google.com/view/linkso) dataset. I have made the necessary files required to curl onto using Kibana and made my ranking function as well. However, I receive an error

```
BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', 'Failed to build [request] after last required field arrived')
```

Here is my code to get the NDCG ranking

```
def get_ndcg(dataframe, input_index="java_lm"):
    ndcg_list = []
    # loop through each qid1
    for i in range(0, len(dataframe["qid1"]), 30):
        qid1_title = es.get(index=input_index, id=dataframe["qid1"][i])['_source']['title']
        
        # load ratings from the json file
        f = open("qids/" + input_index + "/" + str(dataframe["qid1"][i]) + ".json")
        data = json.load(f)

        _search = ranking(dataframe["qid1"][i], qid1_title, ratings=data)
        
        result = es.rank_eval(index=input_index, body=_search)
        
        ndcg = result['metric_score']
        ndcg_list.append(ndcg)
        
    return ndcg_list
```

The error comes on the es.rank_eval() function

I have the ranking function as

```
def ranking(qid1, qid1_title, ratings):
    _search = {
        "requests": [
            {
            "id": str(qid1),
            "request": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": {
                            "match": {
                                "_id": qid1
                            }
                        },
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "title": {
                                        "query": qid1_title,
                                        "boost": 3.0,
                                        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "body": {
                                        "query": qid1_title,
                                        "boost": 0.5,
                                        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "answer": {
                                        "query": qid1_title,
                                        "boost": 0.5,
                                        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "ratings": ratings
            }
        ],
        "metric": {
            "dcg": {
                "k": 10,
                "normalize": True
            }
        }
    }
    return _search
```

Under _search, my ratings file is a json with the format

```
[
{"_index": "java_lm", "_id": "15194804", "rating": 0},
{"_index": "java_lm", "_id": "18264178", "rating": 0},
{"_index": "java_lm", "_id": "16225177", "rating": 1},
{"_index": "java_lm", "_id": "16445238", "rating": 0},
{"_index": "java_lm", "_id": "17233226", "rating": 0}
]
```

And my PUT command on Kibana for loading the template is

```
PUT /java_lm
{
  "settings": {
    "similarity": {
      "LM": {
        "type": "LMDirichlet",
        "mu": 2000
      }
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "porter_stem"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "similarity": "LM"
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "similarity": "LM"
      },
      "answer": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "similarity": "LM"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't seem to find where I am going wrong. Could anyone comment on how to rectify?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes when the json file is incorrectly created for ranking of the documents. The json file needs to be checked to have as many attributes as needed.